# Is it true that if $f'(x) > g'(x)$ then $f(x) >g(x)$?

Tags: calculus

Let $f, g$ be two real valued functions of $C^2$ class and $f'(x) \gt g'(x)\ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$, is it true that $f(x) \gt g(x)\ \forall x \gt 0$?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Trivially no. Are you sure you meant to ask this question?

Comment: Try adding the condition that $f(0) = g(0)$.

Comment: Draw a picture. Or Take $g(x) = 0$ and ask yourself if $f'(x) >0$ means that $f(x) >0$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Consider $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = 1$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've been mixing functions so badly. Must be careful next time.

Answer (score 1):

If we set $h = f -g$ this is equivalent to asking whether $h' > 0$ implies $h > 0$ for all of $\mathbb{R}$. But this is trivially false, as $h = x$ shows.The intuition that might lead one to ask this is that it is true that if $h' > 0$, and $h(x) \geq 0$ at some point $x$, then for all $y > x$ we have $h(y) > 0$. But this actually shows why we have a bit of a problem. See, if $h' \geq c > 0$ for some fixed $c$, then it's actually quite easy to show $h$ has to be less than 0 at some point (Hint: use the evaluation theorem from the fundamental theorem of calculus to show $\lim\limits_{x \to -\infty} h(x) = -\infty$).

Answer (score 1):

We can have $f(x)\lt g(x)$ everywhere.  Let $f(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x \frac{1}{1+t^2}\,dt$ and let $g(x)=100$.

Comment: Or let $g(x) = 0$, or maybe $g(x) = 1$, and let $f(x) = -e^{-x}$.